# Populating an array outside a function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is a sample of what doesn't work:

```
var array_one = [];
array_one=['a','b','c'];
```

Declaring and populating the array outside any function doesn't work, but

```
var array_one = [];
function do_something(){
   array_one=['a','b','c'];
}
```

does, because it's inside a function. Why?

Comment: What exactly would you expect that to do? If you intended `array_one = ['a','b','c'];` you're just missing an `=`. Or are you trying to refer separately to `['a']`, `['b']`, and `['c']`, changing them to `null` perhaps?

Comment: again, my error.. in a real code... there is a '=', i will correct the question, but that will void the answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_one['a','b','b']` is not syntax to populate an array - I'm not really sure what it does actually.

If you do `array_one = ['a','b','c']` then you replace the variable with a new array. (The difference between this and populating an array is that other references to the previous array will still have the old value.)

To add values to the array, use `array_one.push('a')`.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing here is not initialization but instead member lookup.  The expression is parsed as `array_one[<member name>]`.  In this case member_name is achieved by evaluating `'a', 'b', 'c'`.  This uses the comma operator so the 3 expressions are evaluated in order and the result of the expression is the final expression: `'c'`.  This means your code is effectively doing the following

```
array_one['c'];
```

It sounds like what you want is instead

```
array_one = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```